# Perceptual quality measures for images

Tags: image, image-processing, measurement

I'm currently working on algorithm for denoising images. I need to compare my algorithm with other, existing algorithms, but to do so I need a good quality measure.
The main goal for such measure is to be close to human perception skills. I know, that it is almost impossible, but there are good perceptual measures for audio signals. Are there any similar algorithms for images?

Right now I'm using simple measures, such as mean squared error (MSE), signal to noise ratio (SNR) etc...
And for your information, I'm currently implementing this in matlab

Comment: JPG seems to have worked toward that, which is why it is lossy, to reduce size but keep high quality, if you use little compression. They may have a paper that explains the rationale behind their work, and their references may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I will do a little research. Thanks for pointing me the direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you check out SSIM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) ? The following page (http://www.ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/research/ssim/) gives you a real example on how SSIM works compared to MSE.

Comment: It seems that it's what I was looking for. Thank you!